# Trigger an event when the browser back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

I am trying to run some code when the browser back button is clicked.

How can i found out browser's back button with out changing the browser history?

I tried the code below.
 I got an exception in the `else` block saying: "event is not defined".

```js
window.onunload = HandleBackFunctionality();
  function HandleBackFunctionality()
  {
    if(window.event)
    {
      if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
      {
        alert("Browser back button is clicked…");
      } else {
        alert("Browser refresh button is clicked…");
      }
    } else {
      if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1)
      {
        alert("Browser refresh button is clicked…");
      }
      if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2)
      {
        alert("Browser back button is clicked…");
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16164210/803925

Comment: Sorry for half question ..... Below are the extension
 
with out changing the browser history(My project need browser history as tease).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // do something
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick respond....
Your code is working fine after me after i added the JqueryMobile.js file.
is it possible to do this with out adding that JqueryMobile.js file, only adding the jquery.1.11.1 .js file...

Comment: It needs jqueryMobile Check here http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/UKJRM/ .Any issue while including it ?Its small js anyway ,its not at all heavy.

Comment: Some class added to my html pages after i added the jquerymobile.js 
my total view is disturbed.That's y i will ask....

Comment: @user3915009 Some classes are added OK ? See as long as you dont use jquerymobile CSS , styling will not be added to your html.Check which classes are added .And which are giving Css.So in your native HTML use OTHER classes like `sampleClass` To `sampleClass1` Like this,And use these classes in  CSS Like `sampleClass1{ADD_HERE_STYLING}`

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Besides the fact that you should not initially trigger the event and to `.unload = FunctionName` and not `.unload=FunctionName()` and that you need to pass the `event`-argument I checked the code in the browser.

`currentTarget` is empty - this totally makes sense as there is no event-target like onclick but it is just the site reloading/unloading.

Please debug the code by yourself by using this and fit it to your needs:
window.onunload = HandleBackFunctionality;

```
function HandleBackFunctionality(event)
{
  console.log(event, window.event);
}
```

You will see that currentTarget is not set (while event is).

Comment: Hi thank's for respond .
window.onunload = HandleBackFunctionality;
window.onunload();
i write like this in header part ...
even though i got the same exception

Comment: Yes you says right
currentTarget is empty ....
How to i found out the browser back button... i already try many ways no use....

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that works for me with IOS safari.

```
  <script>
     window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
     var pagehistory = event.persisted || 
                     ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                          window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
     if ( pagehistory ) {
    // back button event - Do whatever.   
      }
      });
  </script>
```